# If statement in AngularJs not removing elements after update from 1.0.8

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

So I have this div:

```
<div ng-if="myCheck">
content
</div>
```

I am changing myCheck in my AngularJs controller that controls the page this div is located in.
By default it is set to false, which makes the div element not appear.

If myCheck is changed from false to true after some action on the page,  the div element appears like ti should.

The problem is that after the div has appeared one time, it will not be hidden if myCheck gets set to false again. Instead I will be getting copies of the same div when I set myCheck to false and then to true multiple times.

This was not the case on 1.0.8 version but is on every newer version.
What could be the cause and how to bypass it?

This is what changes the conditionals in controller:

```
$scope.$watch('form.myValue', function (newVal, oldVal) {
            if (typeof newVal != 'undefined') {
                switch (newVal.code) {
                    case "case1":
                        $scope.myCheck1 = true;
                        $scope.myCheck2 = false;
                        $scope.myCheck3 = false;
                        break;
                    case "case2":
                        $scope.myCheck2 = true;
                        $scope.myCheck1 = false;
                        $scope.myCheck3 = false;
                        break;
                    case "case3:
                        $scope.myCheck3 = true;
                        $scope.myCheck1 = false;
                        $scope.myCheck2 = false;
                        break;
                }
            }
        }, true);
```

I use a multiselect dropdown box which makes form.myValue have a value and switch works according to that value.

Comment: Could you add the controller's code? Is your `<div>` inside an ng-repeat or any other directive that creates a child scope?

Comment: Updated my post. And no, it's just in a div that has the corresponding ng-controller tag in it.

Comment: _Instead I will be getting copies of the same div_ - Are you saying that you see multiple divs on the screen then? Does the div or the content have some additional directives?

Comment: No, they are exactly the same. I have like 12 input fields for each case so after 2 changes it will be 24 + forms that are displayed all the time. So yes, copies of the same divs.

Comment: Also worth mentioning maybe that I am now using angularJS 1.2.23. I also tried many other version and it's the same everywhere except 1.0.8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ng-if is not present in angular 1.0.8 stable version. 
https://code.angularjs.org/1.0.8/docs/api

It was added in subsequent versions

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try `ng-show="myCheck"`, it could help :o

Comment: I am not able to use ng-show and ng-hide in my case. I need to completely remove the element from HTML with ng-if , in case of false value.